# Trouble using PHP package

Tags: php

I installed the following composer package:
`composer require weew/timer`...
(https://github.com/weew/timer)

The namespace in the Timer source is: `namespace Weew\Timer;`

I have this autoload code at the top of the file:
`require_once __DIR__ . '/vendor/autoload.php';`

But, in trying to use it...

when using this code:

`use Weew\Timer;`

Result: `Class 'Weew\Timer' not found`

when using this code:

`use weew\timer;`

Result: `Class 'weew\timer' not found`

when removing the `use` altogether:

Result: `Class 'Timer' not found`

When using this code:
`use Timer;`

Result: `The use statement with non-compound name 'Timer' has no effect`

How do I need to load this stupid thing????

Comment: has it got the correct file permissions set?

Comment: Huh? I installed using composer.

Comment: still.. it's always worth checking the file permissions are set correctly, e.g. running using sudo (I know you probably didn't) will make the owner root:root on file creation .. so is worth checking

Comment: Did you run `composer dumpautoload` after you ran `composer install`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The namespace is `Weew\Timer` and the class is `Timer`. Try: `use Weew\Timer\Timer;`

Answer (score 2):

A *namespace* is not the same as a *class name*. So when you say:

> The namespace in the Timer source is: `namespace Weew\Timer;`

That means you should be referencing class (and sometimes function and constant) names which *begin* with `Weew\Timer\`. In this case, the declaration is `class Timer`, so the full name is `Weew\Timer\Timer`.

However, you tried to reference a class *called* `Weew\Timer`

> Class 'Weew\Timer' not found

The `use` statement is optional, so to start with, use the full class name:

```
$timer = new Weew\Timer\Timer;
```

Then, to save typing that in full, you can add a `use` statement to give either the class or the namespace a local alias in the file, e.g.

```
use Weew\Timer as T;
$timer = new T\Timer;
```

or:

```
use Weew\Timer\Timer as T;
$timer = new T;
```

The common case is to alias the namespace (or class) to just the last section, so there is a short-cut syntax for that:

```
use Weew\Timer; // same as "use Weew\Timer as Timer;"
$timer = new Timer\Timer;
```

or:

```
use Weew\Timer\Timer; // same as "use Weew\Timer\Timer as Timer;"
$timer = new Timer;
```

Comment: Thanks for the full explanation.